# Javascript async/await response not ready

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I am having difficulties getting and moving a response from the following functions in a chain.
The values exist further up but however I try to pass them down, the output always ends up empty.

I'm new to async/await in nodejs, but assumed they didn't need to be resolved like or with a promise.

```
let output = {
  keywords: [],
  steps: [],
  twitter: []
}

async function requestGoogle (output) {
  const GoogleResponse = await (
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const loc = utilities.checkOrigin()
      googleMaps.directions({
        origin: loc.origin,
        destination: loc.destination
      }, (error, response) => {
        if (error) resolve(error)
        resolve({
          response
        })
      })
    })
  )
  return GoogleResponse
}

async function requestTwitter (output) {
  try {
    const loc = utilities.checkOrigin()
    const twitterParams = {
      count: details.twitter.count,
      geocode: loc.lat + loc.long + details.radius,
      lang: details.lang,
      result_type: 'recent'
    }
    await output.keywords.map(keyword => {
      TwitterClient.get('search/tweets', {q: 'query'}, (error, tweets, response) => {
        if (error) console.log(error)
        tweets.statuses.map(tweet => {
          output['twitter'].push({
            text: tweet.text
          })
        })
      })
    })
    return output
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('++ requestTwitter flow', error)
  }
}

flow.commuteCheck = () => {
  return requestGoogle(output)
  .then(requestTwitter(output))
  .then(console.log(output))
}
```

The response is unmodified and empty:

```
{ keywords: [], steps: [], twitter: [] }
```

[full file on Github](https://github.com/TomFirth/commuteCheck/blob/master/flow/commuteCheck.js)

Comment: *Way* too much code. Reduce the problem to an [mcve] demonstrating the issue, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.then(requestTwitter(output))` **calls** `requestTwitter(output)` and passes its return value (a promise) into `then`. But `then` expects a callback, not a promise. Similarly with `.then(console.log(output))`.

You probably meant to wrap those in functions:

```
flow.commuteCheck = () => {
  return requestGoogle(output)
  .then(() => requestTwitter(output))
  // ---^^^^^^
  .then(() => console.log(output))
  // ---^^^^^^
}
```

---

FWIW, if `requestGoogle` and `requestTwitter` don't have to run in series, you can overlap them so the requests run concurrently:

```
flow.commuteCheck = () => {
  return Promise.all([
    requestGoogle(output),
    requestTwitter(output)
  ]).then(() => console.log(output));
}
```

---

It's also probably worth noting that in both cases, the promise resolves with no useful value for the caller. You might have it resolve with `output`. To provent crosstalk between requests, you could also make `output` not be a module global that gets reused, but instead an object you create for each request:

```
flow.commuteCheck = () => {
  const output = output = {
    keywords: [],
    steps: [],
    twitter: []
  };
  return Promise.all([
    requestGoogle(output),
    requestTwitter(output)
  ]).then(() => {
    console.log(output);
    return output;
  });
}
```